# Tricks to simplify basic arithmetic expressions?

Tags: arithmetic

I am doing a problem set and have several formulas that are quite ugly such as $$b=\left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} \left(\frac{m}{p_r + p_b \left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} }\right)$$
To see if any of them can be simplified, I plug them into Wolfram Alpha and check. But that's not going to work on a test. I need someway to quickly check if a given expression can be simplified.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$b=\left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} \left(\frac{m}{p_r + p_b \left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} }\right)=$$
$$= \frac{m\left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}}}{p_r + p_b \left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} }=$$
$$= \frac{m}{p_r\left(\frac{3p_b}{2p_r}\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\rho}} + p_b  }.$$

Does this look simpler?

Comment: Yes, I should have tried substituting a variable $c$ in place. That would have been obvious had I done that. Smart!

Comment: But I'm more just concerned with that...every time I have to simplify, I use wolfram alpha. I mean, its not bad for multiplication addition, etc but the exponents get me confused.

Comment: The unnecessary large brackets were also confusing.

Comment: Oh, that's because I had to plug stuff in. It was how I kept it clear in my head where I needed to copy and paste the latex. But I see your point

Comment: I wish I could keep my head clean. Brackets don't help : )